# How to "auto" repeat evil-yank?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, text-editing

I'm not from a vim background so I remap a lot of the evil commands and keys to fit my needs. I know you can use `evil-repeat` but I like the following better to quickly kill a few lines:

```el
(defun evil-delete-or-repeat-delete-line ()
  (interactive)
  (if (or (eq last-command this-command)
          (eq last-command 'evil-line))
      (progn
        (setq this-command 'evil-line)
        (call-interactively 'evil-repeat)
        (kill-new (concat (cadr kill-ring) (car kill-ring))))
    (call-interactively 'evil-delete)))
```

This function repeats deleting lines if I press the `evil-delete` key multiple times and also preserves the `evil-delete` functionality. It appends every subsequent kills to the kill ring, too. This works with the following binding:

```el
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "x") 'evil-delete-or-repeat-delete-line)
```

I would like to have something similar for `evil-yank`. For this the cursor should move to the next line after every call. I tried but couldn't get it to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: First, can you show your code that doesn't work?  Second, can you clarify: do you want to yank the same text repeatedly, or do you want to step through the kill-ring on each successive call?

Comment: @Dan In "evil-speak" yank means copy, confusing I know....I would like to copy a line move to the next line and then copy again if I press the key again. The code was in my scratch buffer and is lost now ;) But I will try it again and add the code to my question then.

Comment: @Dan It worked now, I posted the answer, don't know what went wrong in my first try, I thought it had to be a bigger problem for some reason and posted it here. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again and now it works:

```el
(defun evil-copy-or-repeat-copy-line ()
  (interactive)
  (if (or (eq last-command this-command)
          (eq last-command 'evil-line))
      (progn
        (forward-line 1)
        (setq this-command 'evil-line)
        (call-interactively 'evil-repeat)
        (kill-new (concat (cadr kill-ring) (car kill-ring))))
    (call-interactively 'evil-yank)))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "w") 'evil-copy-or-repeat-copy-line)
```